# how to update table item in dynamodb from sqs msg payload but not overwrite the table structure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

i have the following chain: lambda->sns->sqs-> ec2 script->dynamodb table.

the test event for lambda

```
{
  "body": {
    "MessageAttributes": {
      "vote": {
        "Type": "String",
        "StringValue": "b"
      },
      "voter": {
        "Type": "String",
        "StringValue": "count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

originally the table should have 1 partition and 2 attributes - a and b, created with this json code:

```
{
  "voter": {
    "S": "count"
  },
  "a": {
    "N": "11"
  },
  "b": {
    "N": "20"
  }
}
```

[image: ll]

the issue is in ec2 script that runs continuously. It has a function update_count(vote) that should just increase the existing a or b by 1. The code:

```
def update_count(vote):
    logging.info('update count....')
    
    table.update_item(
        Key={'voter': 'count'},
        UpdateExpression="ADD #vote = #vote + :incr",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={'#vote': vote},
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':incr': 1}
    )
```

when i send my test event it overwrites my dynamodb table and it has the following structure:

[image: zdf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `UpdateItem` will never overwrite attributes which are not set in the `UpdateExpression`.

I would ensure that you have no other code which is inadvertantly overwriting your item, perhaps from a Lambda function listening to a stream, or another function being called unknowingly in your application.

You can enable DynamoDB Dataplane logs on Cloudtrail to understand what is happening:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html

Comment: i think the problem is that my structure is not nested properly. i m actually trying to get the cur value from table using table.get_item() then simply add 1 and update_item

Comment: The code snippet you shared would not overwrite the item from your first screenshot to your second. Something else is at play.

Comment: wait, what do u mean?  once i send test event it does overwrite.